# Is every bornological space measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, gn.general-topology, pr.probability

Every topological space is measurable, since we may canonically equip a topological space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. A bornological space is like a topological space, except the structure described "bounded" sets instead of "open" sets. Similarly, the morphisms are "bounded" instead of "continuous".

Formally, that a bornological space is a pair $(X, \mathbf B)$, where $\mathbf B$ is a set of subsets of $X$ which covers $X$, is downward-closed, and is closed under finite unions [[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) | [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bornological+set)]. We may trivially assign a measurable structure to every bornological space by defining simply $\mathcal B = \sigma(\mathbf B)$, the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains the bornology $\mathbf B$.

What kind of measure theory can one do in this setting? For example, are there necessary and sufficient conditions for a bornological space to admit a non-trivial measure? Is there a classification of [$\sigma$-ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ideal) for a bornological space?

Comment: Since it is downward-closed, you get lots of power-sets contained in your sigma-algebra.  So is this a question on measurable cardinals?

Answer (score 1):

Usually we find a measure space and look into its bornological stuff, not conversely, a helpful reference may be founded in this book:
*U. H¨ohle and S. E. Rodabaugh, eds., Mathematics of fuzzy sets: logic, topology and measure
theory, Handbook Series*
Another reference may be S. T. Hu's research papers.